# How to call low-level receive() function from ethers front end?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I have a solidity smart contract receive function which is:

```
    receive() payable external onlyOwner() {
        uint256 share = msg.value / recipients.length; 

        for(uint i=0; i < recipients.length; i++){
            recipients[i].transfer(share);
        }    
        emit TransferReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
```

I can call it from the remix like this:

[image: receive function call from remix]

how can I call it from my react front end using ethers while sending some ether with msg.value?

Comment: What did you tried with ethers.js? can you share the code?
I think just make contract interface, and call receive function.
`contract.receive({value: YOUR_ETH_WITH_BIGNUMBER_AND_DECIMAL})`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can call `receive` function on demand. it gets called automatically every time your contract receives ether. That is why it cannot have `return` statement.